# In which cases can we find the tikz key "execute at begin to" useful

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

In the the tikz/pgf manual, we can read in the subsection "14.13 The to path operation"   about the key `/tikz/execute at begin to` but without any examples on how to use it concretely. So I am asking for some examples that may demonstrate how this key may be useful in practical cases. So please give one example by answer.

Comment: There already exist examples on this site, e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129539/121799) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277072/121799). What precisely do you want to know about this key?

Comment: To find such things, do a google search with `site:tex.stackexchange.com "execute at begin to"` (the " are important). [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/276624/121799) is another cool example IMHO.

Comment: I just want to know how to use it with some working examples

Comment: I would have liked to have some simpler examples just to grab the idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, here is a rather simple but perhaps not completely pointless example which draws a line parallel to the line you want to draw.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
illustrate at begin to/.style=
    {to path={
      (\tikztostart) -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
    },
    execute at begin to={
    \draw[blue] ($(\tikztostart)!5pt!90:(\tikztotarget)$) --
    ($(\tikztotarget)!5pt!-90:(\tikztostart)$) node[midway,above,sloped]{I'm parallel};}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[illustrate at begin to] (0,0) to (5,1);
\draw[illustrate at begin to] (0,-2) to (4,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for fun, another application, using [Jake's complete sines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25689/121799) and motivated by (my interpretation of) [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/452904/121799). (No, this trick does not work for curved paths, just in case you're wondering. ;-)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,calc}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{complete sines}{initial}
{
    \state{initial}[
        width=+0pt,
        next state=sine,
        persistent precomputation={\pgfmathsetmacro\matchinglength{
            \pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength / int(\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength/\pgfdecorationsegmentlength)}
            \setlength{\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{\matchinglength pt}
        }] {}
    \state{sine}[width=\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]{
        \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{-0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{-0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
}
    \state{final}{}
}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{fancy sines/.style={#1,decoration={
            complete sines,
            segment length=3mm,
            amplitude=1mm
        },decorate,to path={
      (\tikztostart) -- 
      ($(\tikztotarget)!{-5*\pgflinewidth}!-135:(\tikztostart)$)
      (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
    },
    execute at begin to={\foreach \X in {1,...,5}
    {\draw[decorate,#1]
    ($(\tikztostart)!{\X*\pgflinewidth}!45:(\tikztotarget)$) 
    -- ($(\tikztotarget)!{(-5+\X)*\pgflinewidth}!-135:(\tikztostart)$);}}}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}    
\draw[fancy sines=blue] (0,0) to (0,-3);
\draw[fancy sines=red] (0,0) to (3,0);
\draw[fancy sines=green!60!black] (3,0) to (0,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]